# how can i split lists ? should i use Input.split(;)?

Tags: python, list

I want to take input from user in the form of numbers **separated space or semi-colon.**
When the user enters list something like this 
`Lists: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3`
I want numbers before semi-colon to be put in one list and numbers after the semi-colon to be put in a different list. So for above input, my two lists should be `[1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3] and [4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3]`.
Should I try split function? My aim is to return a list with all the elements that occur multiple times in an ascending order.

```
while True:

    original_string = input("Lists: ")
    if not original_string:
            exit()

    first_split = original_string.split(';')
    first_list, second_list = [elem.split(' ') for elem in first_split]

    print(first_list)
    print(second_list)
#how can returns the list of all the elements that occur multiple times in both lists and the return list should be in ascending order
```

My output should look like this

```
Lists: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3

[2, 3]

Lists : 1 1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 4 5 6

[]

Lists : ;

[]

Lists:
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: please use dot when you write text. I don't know where are ends of sentences.

Comment: try before ask. And show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a first split (defined by a `;` ).
Then as second one (define by space char), for each element defined in the first split.

```
first_split = original_string.split(';')
first_list, second_list = [elem.split(' ') for elem in first_split]
```

You may want to do some processing on the data, for instance: transform to integer and remove extra spaces or empty elements.

Comment: my code is working till this part now my first_list have elemets before ; and second_list have elements after ;
but how can I find the elements occurring multiple times in these lists ?

Comment: You can use a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`list_of_lists = [[int(x) for x in lis.split()] for lis in input().split(';')]`

To find elements occurring more than once, you could use this

```py
    from collections import defaultdict
    dic = defaultdict(int)
    for ele in a_list:
        if dic[ele] == 1:
            print('a repeating element found')
        dic[ele] += 1
```

Comment: but how can I find the elements occurring multiple times in these lists ?

Comment: I hope this clarifies it now

Comment: Can you check I have update the question of how my output should look like ? thanks

Comment: @pulkit You have all the logic now, the final formatting of output you should try on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. I have added comments for better understanding.

```
original_string = input("Lists: ")
splitted_input = original_string.split(';') # split the input string into two lists of String
list1 = [int(i) for i in splitted_input[0].split()] # convert first String (before semi-colon) into list of int
list2 = [int(i) for i in splitted_input[1].split()] # convert second String (after semi-colon) into list of int
l1 = list(set([x for x in list1 if list1.count(x) > 1])) # List of only repeated numbers in list1
l2 = list(set([x for x in list2 if list2.count(x) > 1])) # List of only repeated numbers in list2
l = l1 + l2
final_list = list(set([x for x in l if l.count(x) > 1])) # List of only repeated numbers in l
final_list_sorted = sorted(final_list) # sort the list in ascending order
print('Two lists before and after semi-colin are: ', list1, list2)
print('Two lists with only repeated numbers are: ', l1, l2)
print('Final list with repeated numbers in both the lists in an ascending order is: ', final_list_sorted)
```

Output:

```
Lists: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3
Two lists before and after semi-colin are:  [1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3] [4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3]
Two lists with only repeated numbers are:  [1, 2, 3] [2, 3, 4]
Final list with repeated numbers in both the lists in an ascending order is:  [2, 3]


Lists: 1 1 2 3 4 5; 2 3 4 5 6
Two lists before and after semi-colin are:  [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
Two lists with only repeated numbers are:  [1] []
Final list with repeated numbers in both the lists in an ascending order is:  []


Lists: ;
Two lists before and after semi-colin are:  [] []
Two lists with only repeated numbers are:  [] []
Final list with repeated numbers in both the lists in an ascending order is:  []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list expressions like `sorted()`, `split()`, and `set()` to get the desired output like the following:

```
while True:

    original_string = input("Lists: ")
    if not original_string:
            exit()
    # get lists
    l1, l2 =  original_string.split(';')[0].split(), original_string.split(';')[1].split()
    # print lists
    print("l1: ", l1)
    print("l2: ", l2)
    # get occurences
    occurences_in_l1 = sorted(set([e for e in l1 if l1.count(e) > 1]))
    occurences_in_l2 = sorted(set([e for e in l1 if l2.count(e) > 1]))
    # print occurences
    print("sorted occurences l1: ", occurences_in_l1)
    print("sorted occurences l2: ", occurences_in_l2)
```

output:

```
Lists: 1 3 4 2 1 2 1 3; 4 4 2 4 3 2 4 4 3 1 3
l1:  ['1', '3', '4', '2', '1', '2', '1', '3']
l2:  ['4', '4', '2', '4', '3', '2', '4', '4', '3', '1', '3']
sorted occurences l1:  ['1', '2', '3']
sorted occurences l2:  ['2', '3', '4']
```